# [help]RoR, Chartkick, bar chart with all users and number of endorsements for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

**Edit: I'ts been over 3 weeks now, and i can't seem to solve the problem without making even more problems. Can anyone be so kind and take a look please??**

---

I want to create a bar chart listing all users and number of their endorsements. Would be nice to also have a drilldown on each number to display the number of endorsements the user got for each month in current year. Like:

User1 - 5

User2 - 8

User3 - 3

And clicking on each number would drill down and show data for the clicked user like this:

January - 2

February - 2

March - 1

And I am totally lost and have no idea how to approach this, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

In my view all I managed to do was to just show a blank chart with users listed below it:

```
<% provide(:title, "Statistics") %>
<h1>Statistics</h1>

<%= bar_chart @users.group(:name) %>

<% end %>
```

I am using chartkick and dateslices instead of groupdate because im using SQlite.

Also, to get the number of endorsements i have to do something like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <ul class="user">
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.inbound_endorsements.count %>
  </ul>
```

where @users is basically User.all

You can see the relations below.

---

Now some info about my Users and endorsements controllers/models with cut out parts of unrelevant info like password settings and such

Users Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inbound_endorsements, class_name: "Endorsement",
                                 foreign_key: "endorsed_user_id",
                                 dependent: :destroy
  has_many :outbound_endorsements, class_name:  "Endorsement",
                                  foreign_key: "endorsing_user_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :endorsing_users, through: :inbound_endorsements, source: :endorsing_user
  has_many :endorsed_users, through: :outbound_endorsements, source: :endorsed_user

.
.
.

  # Endorses a user.
  def endorse(other_user, comment)
    outbound_endorsements.create(endorsed_user_id: other_user.id, comment: comment)
  end

  # Unendorses a user.
  def unendorse(other_user)
    outbound_endorsements.find_by(endorsed_user_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if this is endorsing the other user.
  def endorsing?(other_user)
    Endorsement.current.exists?(endorsing_user: self, endorsed_user: other_user)
  end

  # Returns true if this can endorse other user.
  def can_endorse?(other_user)
    if (current_outbound_endorsements_count < 3)
      unless endorsing?(other_user)
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end

  def current_outbound_endorsements_count
    outbound_endorsements.current.count
  end

.
.
.
```

Endorsements model:

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorsing_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :endorsed_user, class_name: "User"
  validates :endorsing_user_id, presence: true
  validates :endorsed_user_id, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140}
  scope :current, -> { where(created_at:  (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now)) }
end
```

And this is my static_pages controller, with only this defined for the statistics page where i want the chart displayed:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :require_admin, only: :statistics

  def home
    if logged_in?
    end
  end

  def statistics
    @users = User.all
    @endorsements = Endorsement.all
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Any help and tips will be greatly appreciated!

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this? If you know such, let me know!

Comment: It's been over 3 weeks without any help, anyone kind enough to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 months I've managed to solve my problem.. Well, not exactly, I cannot get the drilldown to work, but managed to make a simple bar chart for all users that have endorsements, users with 0 are not displayed.

This is how I did it:

In my static pages controller for the statistics page i made something like this:

```
def statistics
    @users = User.all
    @endorsements = Endorsement.all
    @data = @users.map { |user|
            amount = user.inbound_endorsements.joins(:endorsed_user).group(:name).count
              if !amount.empty?
                {name: user.name, data: amount}
              end
            }
  end
```

and in my view for statistics I made this:

```
<% provide(:title, "Statistics") %>
<h1>Statistics</h1>
<%= pie_chart({"Users" => @users.count, "Endorsements" => @endorsements.count}) %>
<%= column_chart @data.compact, library: {yAxis: {allowDecimals: false}} %>
```

@data.compact removed the nil values from the hash, resulting in a hash looking like this:

```
[{:name=>"Jess Corwin", :data=>{"Jess Corwin"=>1}}, {:name=>"Rhiannon Nicolas", :data=>{"Rhiannon Nicolas"=>1}}, {:name=>"Assunta Pfeffer", :data=>{"Assunta Pfeffer"=>2}}, {:name=>"Rafaela Farrell", :data=>{"Rafaela Farrell"=>1}}, {:name=>"Maurine Hettinger", :data=>{"Maurine Hettinger"=>1}}]
```

And that data resulted in a chart like this:

[image]

Which is satisfactory. Hope this helps someone one day.